# SurrealDB: How to add a day, week, month to a datetime?

Tags: datetime, surrealdb

I need to add "2 weeks" to `time::now()`'s value.

For example:

```
-- Now: 2023-07-09T21:48:57.676702494Z
time::now() 

-- Two weeks later than now: 2023-07-21T21:48:57.676702494Z
time::now() + <SOMETHING>
```

How can I add to a datetime value a week, a day or an hour etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2W is the  you're looking for, as shown in the example here: https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/datamodel/datetimes

Try:

```
return type::datetime(time::now()+2W)
```